# Obtain all possible outcomes of a two-variable function - Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

As a beginner in Python I'm having trouble trying to solve a specific task over a function I have, and I was hoping someone could give me a hand since I can't find a way to do it, I'd really appreciate it. So without further ado this is my issue:

I have a function I made that takes two inputs. It's quite big, but for the inquiry's sake let's say it could be something like this:

```
def trd(SPREAD,STOP):
    money = SPREAD * STOP - 10 * STOP
    return(money)
```

The values of both inputs would be ranges of floats with a difference of 0.01 from each other, so their possible values could be these for example:

SPREAD: 2.50, 2.51, 2.52 ... until 3.50

STOP: 1.00, 1.01, 1.02 ... until 1.50

and the output, named here "money", could be any amount, like -10054.55 EUR or 8763.20 EUR.

The thing is that I'd need to obtain all of the possible trd() outputs for all of the combinations of those two inputs in either a Pandas dataframe (so the columns would be the SPREAD values and the rows the STOP ones or the other way around) or maybe a Numpy matrix, whichever is best to later represent in a density plot or a contour plot (where the horizontal ax would be SPREAD, the vertical one STOP and those "money" outputs" would be colors).

How could I get there?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: All possible outputs within a certain range? Or "all possible" outputs? (which would be impossible)

Comment: Hi Jesse, I mean all possible ouptuts within a range, so for example "SPREAD" would have values from 2.50 to 3.50 with a difference from each other of 0.01 (so 100 possibilities in total). So if I can have 100 possibilities for "SPREAD" and 50 possibilities for "STOP" I understand I'd have 5000 outputs for my function trd() that later i'd have to represent. Sorry if it wasn't clear!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answers above are correct. However, if you are anyway going to pack the results in numpy array / pandas dataframe, I would suggest to go with double list comprehension and numpy functions:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def trd(SPREAD,STOP):
    money = SPREAD * STOP - 10 * STOP
    return(money)

def build_matrix(spread_lo, spread_hi, spread_range, 
                 stop_lo, stop_hi, stop_range):

    spread_list = np.arange(spread_lo, spread_hi, spread_range)
    stop_list = np.arange(stop_lo, stop_hi, stop_range)

    wannabe_matrix = [[trd(spread, stop) 
                       for spread in spread_list]
                      for stop in stop_list]

    # Transpose it as you wish. Note that wannabe_matrix is list of numpy arrays, 
    # so transposition is easier after you build pandas dataframe
    df = pd.DataFrame(wannabe_matrix, columns=spread_list, index=stop_list).T

    return df


build_matrix(1.50, 2.00, 0.05, 1.0, 1.25, 0.05)
```

Answer (score 2):

Okay so:

Firstly since you are dealing with floats, you can create a custom step function to use which takes a lower bound, upper bound and step.

Then you want to iterate for each SPREAD value, you want to complete a cycle of the STOP range. This can be achieved with a nested loop. In below, I'm just printing out the values, you can look up how to input these values into whatever data structure you wish.

```
def trd(SPREAD,STOP):
    money = SPREAD * STOP - 10 * STOP
    return(money)

def irange(start, stop, step):
    x = start
    while x < stop:
        yield x
        x += step

def jrange(start, stop, step):
    x = start
    while x < stop:
        yield x
        x += step

for i in irange(2.50,3.50,0.01):
    for j in jrange(1.00,1.50,0.01):
        print(i) #current value of SPREAD
        print(j) #current value of STOP
        z = trd(i,j) #current value of trd(SPREAD,STOP)
        print(z)
```

Comment: That looks great, I will combine it with pandas.DataFrame.at to fill a dataframe that later i'll use to represent everything. Thanks!! ;).

Comment: Also see below @OliverRadini's answer and give a +10 :) He has kindly shown you how to put this into a list if you choose not to use Pandas or Numpy.

Answer (score 2):

My answer is not too disimilar from Jesse's, but as I've written it out I thought I may as well include it. I've used a dictionary comprehension to show the results for the range of possible inputs. The possible inputs are created from a list comprehension:

```
def trd(SPREAD,STOP):
    money = SPREAD * STOP - 10 * STOP
    return(money)

max_spread = 0.2
max_stop = 0.2
step = 0.01

spread_values = [i*step for i in range(0, int(max_spread / step))]
stop_values = [i*step for i in range(0, int(max_stop / step))]

results = {
  spread_value: {
    stop_value: trd(spread_value, stop_value)
    for stop_value in
    stop_values
  }
  for spread_value in
  spread_values
}

print(results)
```

Comment: I think I can also use it for the latter representation in an even easier way, so thanks a lot!! ;)

Comment: @JorgePuente I'm glad that was useful, best of luck!